# Are destructors not meant to be called when returning that object (not as a pointer)?

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a function:

```
static Bwah boo(){
   Bwah bwah;
   return bwah;
}
```

And a main function:

```
int main(){
   Bwah boo = Assigner::boo();
   cout << "got here.." << endl;
}
```

The destructor to Bwah is only called once, after the "got here" print.
Is this guaranteed or is this a compiler optimization?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an optimization called Return Value Optimization (RVO). It is a common optimization, but you can't rely on it.

Here are two really excellent links for learning more:

1. First, a really detailed article about [pass by value, rvalue semantics, the return value optimization, and rvalue references and the move constructor and assignment operator in C++0x](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)
2. Second, the good old standby Wikipedia and [their entry on the return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

The Wikipedia article in particular directly addresses your question.  But the other article goes more in depth about the whole issue.

Comment: More info on it if you don't wanna google it:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: Good article on this and related topics: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: I'm editing these links into your answer.  Feel free to back out my change.